# Need to copy files in the same directory with different name

Tags: unix, script, shell-script

I have directory which has several files but has a fixed syntax:-

As is: source_delta_201908_120345.xml
To be: source_normal_201908_120345.xml

So, Need to replace 'delta' with 'normal' and copy multiple files to same directory and once copying is complete, need to delete old files having 'delta' in file  name pattern.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Instead of copying all + deleting old files later, do you allow just moving (renaming) files one by one? What is your research effort? What have you tried? Please respond by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: Hi Kamil,
I have edited and added. pease have a look

Answer (score -1):

Try this help guide to bulk rename with same format.
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-rename-multiple-files-bulk-windows-10

Comment: -1. Link-only answers are low quality. Besides, the question is tagged [tag:unix] and the linked site applies to Windows.